# Get list of available COM-ports

Tags: c++, c, winapi, serial-port

I have a device that appears as COM-interface in my Windows system. My software tries to auto-detect it, means it opens all ports from COM1 to COM20 to see if the correct device responds.

Now my problem is, Windows can have up to 255 COM-ports - and trying to open all of them is way too slow.

So: is there a way to get a list of COM-ports that are really available?

Thanks!

Comment: You can enumerate the DOS devices.

Comment: CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW(L"{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}", buf,..)->CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&dnDevInst, buf,)->CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(dnDevInst, &DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName,..)